# How to make curl post request from python

Tags: python, rest, post, curl

I am trying to make a post request using curl in python but the below script throws error

```
import os

first_name1 = "raj"
last_name1 = "kiran"
full_name = "raj kiran"
headline = "astd"
location1 = "USA"
current_company1 = "ss"

curl_req = 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"first_name":"{0}","last_name":"{1}","current_company":"{2}","title":"{3}","campus":"","location":"{4}","display_name":"{5}","find_personal_email":"true"}' http://localhost:8090'.format(first_name1,last_name1,current_company1,headline,location1,full_name)

os.popen(curl_req)
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to make above program work?

Comment: Why are you doing this when you can use `requests`?

Comment: how can i send post request to this http://localhost:8090 in above format using request?

Comment: read http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is the quotes. Change it to:

```
curl_req = '''curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"first_name":"{0}","last_name":"{1}","current_company":"{2}","title":"{3}","campus":"","location":"{4}","display_name":"{5}","find_personal_email":"true"}' http://localhost:8090'''.format(first_name1,last_name1,current_company1,headline,location1,full_name)
```

But, as mentioned in the comments, `requests` will always be a better choice.

Requests syntax:

```
import requests
post_data = { 
   # all the data you want to send 
}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8090', data=post_data)
print response.text
```

Comment: can you help me to make it using requests?

Answer (score 1):

One good resource I've used for converting a cURL request to Python requests is [curlconverter](https://curl.trillworks.com/). You can enter your cURL request and it will format it for Python `requests`.

As a side note, it can also convert for PHP and Node.js.

Hope that helps!